# Is a "Display Manager" like lightdm or lxdm a requirement for a X11/XWindows?

Tags: x11

Is a "Display Manager" like lightdm or lxdm a requirement for a XWindows?

Right now, I have no intention of installing a desktop like Gnome or KDE, is a "Display Manager" required if I just want to use XWindows?

I believe the answer is no, I wanted to verify with a larger audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. You can start the session manually with something like:

```
$ startx
```

Or just start the X server (say :2):

```
$ sudo X :2
```

and then point your clients to it, for example:

```
$ DISPLAY=:2 xeyes
```